# save pdf on server fpdf

Tags: cakephp, pdf, directory, fpdf

I am generating a pdf with fpdf in cakephp and I try to save it on the server.
I do it like this :
     $fpdf->Output("D:/Files/mypdf.pdf",'F'); 
but it doesn't save. 
I think it doesn't find the folder, but I don't know how specified it?
I have put the all the right on the folder.
I don't know if it is a cakephp restriction or just my directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this 
`$fpdf->Output(WWW_ROOT."files\mypdf.pdf", 'F');`

Answer (score 0):

As this code works fine locally, it's probably server-problem.

**(1)** Are you sure you can create files? Most free servers disallow creating files.

**(2)** Have you tried it with different location e.g. the current root location $fpdf->Output("mypdf.pdf",'F')

Anyway, you should enable error reporting in your index.php. If it was matter of directory not found you would get this result:

```
Warning (2): fopen(D:/Files/mypdf.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory [ROOT\vendor\fpdf\fpdf.php, line 1025]

FPDF error: Unable to create output file: D:/Files/mypdf.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Just  a wild guess but change the slashes to windows style.

```
$fpdf->Output("D:\Files\mypdf.pdf",'F');
```

or even

```
$fpdf->Output("D:\\Files\\mypdf.pdf",'F');
```